# Makefile for subdirectories program in C

Tags: linux, makefile, gnu-make

I have a problem with creating a Makefile for my program. First of all I'll point how my program's directory hast to look like:

- *.o files has to be in main program directory
- *.c files are in src directory
- *.h files are in include directory
- bin folder is for executable file
- lib folder is a place for library files

As I mentioned above I have *.c *.h files already placed in src and include directories. Makefile is located in main program directory. My makefile has to contain vpath or VPATH. 
Using gcc I have to build the whole project. 
pj, pp, pg, pr are functions .c files.
First of all I have to create object files using `gcc -fPIC -c` than from pj.o and pp.o I have to build static library using `ar rs` than build shared library from pg.o and pr.o using `gcc -shared`. All libjp.a and libhgr.so should be placed in lib folder. After that i have to build the whole program using `gcc -o $@ $^ -L./lib -I./include` and place executable file in bin directory.
It's actually not working it's only building the first lib - libjp.a 
Here is my makefile:

```
.PHONY: clean
.SUFFIXES: .c .o .a .so
vpath %.c src
vpath %.h include
%.o: %.c
    gcc -w -fPIC -c $<
lib/libjp.a: pj.o pp.o
    ar rs $@ $<
lib/libgr.so: pg.o pr.o
    gcc -w -shared -o $@ $<
%: %.o
    gcc -o $@ $^ -L./lib -I./include
program: program.o lib/libjp.a lib/libgr.so
program.o: program.c libjp.h libgr.h
pj.o: pj.c
pp.o: pp.c
pg.o: pg.c
pr.o: pr.c
clean:
    rm -f program *.o *.a *.so
```

Thank you for your time and help :)

Comment: What happens when you try to build these files using the command line (i.e. without Make)?

Comment: @Beta If they all are in same directory its compiling fine;
1) Shared library
 `gcc -c program.c gcc -w -fPIC -c pg.c -o pg.o gcc -w -fPIC -c pr.c -o pr.o gcc -shared -o libgr.so pg.o pr.o`
2) Static library
`gcc -c pj.c
gcc -c pp.c
ar rs libjp.a pj.o pp.o`
3) Compiling: 
`gcc program.o -o program libgr.so libjp.a`
It's compiling, and i can run it i mean it's working.

Comment: And can you run the executable when the shared library is in `lib/`? Part of the problem seems to be that the executable cannot find the shared library. There is more than one way to fix this, but I don't know whether you have a solution in place.

Comment: @Beta one of the errors i get when i try to run the executable file is that it can't find libs. I fixed this by simply copying libs which i created to the /lib folder (not /home/usr/download/program/lib but /lib) it fixed this but i guess it's not the best solution. I don't know how to force my compiler and linker to look for libs in lib folder in /home/usr/download/program/lib which is place where i want to place libs for this specific program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use VPATH to locate derived (generated) files.  VPATH can *only* be used with source files.  So, these two lines, and all the associated infrastructure that goes with them, will not work as you expect:

```
vpath %.so lib
vpath %.a lib
```

If you want to understand this more fully you can read http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/how-not-to-use-vpath/

Second, rules like this:

```
%.a: pj.o pp.o
        ar rs $@ $^
        mv *.a ./lib
```

violate the [second rule of makefiles](http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/rules-of-makefiles/).  If you want a target to be created in a subdirectory, then the name of the target must be the full name, in the subdirectory.  And there's no point in using pattern rules if you're going to list the prerequisites explicitly in the pattern.  You can use something like:

```
lib/libjp.a: pj.o pp.o
        ar rs $@ $^
lib/libgr.so: pg.o pr.o
        gcc -w -shared -o $@ $^
```

which means you have to change references to it:

```
program: program.o lib/libjp.a lib/libgr.so
```

and lines like this should be removed:

```
libjp.a: pj.o pp.o
libgr.so: pg.o pr.o
```

There may be other similar changes needed.

Comment: Thank you, now my makefile is working better but still not good.
Here is source:
`.PHONY: clean
.SUFFIXES: .c .o .a .so
vpath %.c src
vpath %.h include
%.o: %.c
    gcc -w -fPIC -c $<
lib/libjp.a: pj.o pp.o
    ar rs $@ $<
lib/libgr.so: pg.o pr.o
    gcc -w -shared -o $@ $<
%: %.o
    gcc -o $@ $^ -L./lib -I./include
program: program.o lib/libjp.a lib/libgr.so
program.o: program.c include/libjp.h include/libgr.h
pj.o: pj.c
pp.o: pp.c
pg.o: pg.c
pr.o: pr.c
 
clean:
    rm -f program *.o *.a *.so`

Comment: It's creating only .a lib file and not automaticly building other program elements.

Comment: There's no way I can help you with a makefile using SO comments.  However, remember that by default make will only build the first explicit target it finds in the makefile.  So you should be sure that whatever target you want built, is listed first.  In this case I assume that's the `program` target.

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort I know that code in SO comments is hard to read so i made a pastebin copy for you https://pastebin.com/cSdJShiD Please have a look at it in your free time, I made a change for program rule to be first like you mentioned but i get now an error: "No rule to make target "program.c"".